# Sitecore Solr Loadbalancing

Tags: azure, solr, sitecore, load-balancing

I am working on a sitecore application where I need to set up 3 node cluster with solr configured in 2 servers and zoo keeper in all 3 servers .So I am looking for some solution to load balance solr instances . We are working on azure windows 2012 vms .The front end application is built on top of siteoCore and we are using IIS as our web server . So what option would be the best without going for a 3rd party load balancer like to use solr's internal load balancer "LBHttpSolrServer" or external azure provided load balancer ? Please suggest me but I can't go for a 3rd party load balancer . We have 5 CD servers . 
Can I go for server farm using Application Request Routing Module ? So where I need to install this in CD servers or in SOLR servers ?

Comment: Hi Deb, which version of Solr are you using? And did you install Solr or are you using Solr VM available on Azure? And just for clarification, do you want to know the best option between LBHttpSolrServer and Azure Load Balancer? Thanks, Vinicius

Comment: We are using solr 4.10.3.I have installed solr and registered solr as a windows service . So wanted to know the best option for solr load balancing . Can I go for IIS server farm ?

Comment: LBHttpSolrServer would be the best option, as you don't want to use 3rd party application and assuming your SOLR is running under a Apache server.

Comment: We are running solr as a windows service . We are not using apache server .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based in all information you have provided, the best approach is deploy LBHttpSolrServer as your load balanced solution.

Please find more info here: [LBHttpSolrServer](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LBHttpSolrServer)

Also, please note even running as Windows Service, it has to have a Path to Executable which runs either Solr or Apache TomCat behind the scene.

Thanks,

Vinicius